# I am trying to write a recursive function in c++ and it keeps causing a stack overflow

Tags: c++, if-statement, recursion, stack-overflow

So i am trying to write a recursive function to count all of the spaces on a grid of characters. It is for a project in which i have to write a program that calculates the score of a simplified game of Go. The board i'm given looks like this http://pastebin.com/7MaFtmmw[1] . All of the open spaces are surrounded. I am supposed to ultimately find which player surrounded more open space. I am not sure how to find how many spaces are surrounded by a specific character. I think i know how to count all of the spaces though. I wrote this code to do so http://pastebin.com/Pd2ds9fw[2] .
I call it from an object of the class that it is in that was declared on the stack, like so; game.countSpaces(0, 0). No matter what, it always causes a stack overflow. I have tried debugging it and it never reaches the last two function calls. It just cycles the first two until visual studio finally crashes.
Can anyone explain why this won't work to find the number of spaces? Why does it cause the stack to overflow?
Also could you give me a hint about how to go after here to count only the spaces one player has surrounded? If not that's fine. But i really really want to know why my initial space counting function doesn't work.
p. s. I didn't declare count because it is a member of the class.

```
void GoScorer::countSpaces(int row, int col)
{
    if((row < 0) || (row >= BOARDSIZE))
            return;
    if((col < 0) || (col >= BOARDSIZE))
            return;
    if (board[row][col] != ' ')
            return;

    count++;

    countSpaces((row - 1), col);
    countSpaces((row + 1), col);
    countSpaces(row, (col - 1));
    countSpaces(row, (col + 1));
    return;
}

  BWB  BW WB BW    
  BWB  BW WB BW    
  BWBBBBW WB BW    
  BWWWWWW WBBBWWWWW
  BBW  WW WWBBBBBBB
   BWWWWW  WB      
   BBBBBWWWWB      
BBBBB  BBWWWBB BBBB
WWWWB   BW WBBBWWWW
  WWB    BWWWB BW  
  WBBBBBBBWBBBBW   
  WWWWWWWWWB  BW   
  WW   WWWWB  BWWWW
WWWWW     WB  BBBBB
BBBBWWW   WB       
  BBBBW   WB  BBBBB
  BBBBWWW WB  BWWWW
     BBBW WB  BW   
       BW WB  BW
```

Comment: if you are going to rate my question badly, could you at least say why? Every time i ask a question with this community, it's nearly pointless. It's terrible too because a lot of perople here really knows what they are talking about

Comment: I did. My code is in the links. Did you read my question? The 2nd pastebin link has all of my code.

Comment: Sorry, they've been removed for some stupid reason probably. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Put the code here, instead of a link to somewhere else.

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the question. Sorry, didn't mean to sound like an asshole a bit ago. I'm just kind of frustrated with not understanding it.

Comment: are you restricted to recursion? what is the container you are using ?
Show us 'board' and 'count'

Comment: Alright. Yes, the assignment said that i need to use a modified flood fill algorithm. I'm adding them to the post.

Comment: Ok I am going to edit my answer to full recursion solution

Answer (score 1):

Your `countSpaces` function will never return. For example, if you start at (2,2), it will recurse to (2, 1) which will then (eventually) recurse to (2, 2) again.

You need to put some sort of check to see if a space has already been counted. One way would be to have another grid with a flag at each point to say whether this position has been counted already.

Answer (score 1):

this is one possible solution of other 1000s possible:

```
  void GoScorer::countSpaces(int row)
    {
        if((row < 0))
                return;


        count+=std::count(std::begin(board[row]), std::end(board[row]),' ');

        countSpaces(row-1);
        return;
    }
```

call it :

```
countSpaces(BOARDSIZE-1)
```

EDIT: if you need a pure recursion method:

```
 int count=0;
 void GoScorer::countSpaces(int row, int col)
 {
        if(col < 0){
             if(row>0){
                    countSpaces((row - 1), BOARDSIZE-1);
                    return;
             }

        }
        if(row < 0){
              return;
        }

        if (board[row][col] == ' '){
              ++count;
        }
        countSpaces(row, col - 1);

        return;
 }
```

call it:

```
countSpaces(BOARDSIZE-1,BOARDSIZE-1);
```

P.S. not tested

Feel free to ask if something is not clear

Comment: As I understood it's not just space counting. It's more similar to fill shape - it must count **connected** spaces. Look at question code - recursion stops on non-space cell.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a recursive function should always call itself under some condition which can and eventually will be false.

There is no point in calling a recursive function (internally) without condition. (But you could conditionally return *before* the call, making that call conditional)

Answer (score -1):

You must mark already counted cell, otherwise it'll cycle infinitely.

For example, it can go left->up->right->down and it'll be in same cell again.

You can add **bool** table same size and mark each cell:

```
void GoScorer::countSpaces(int row, int col)
{
    if((row < 0) || (row >= BOARDSIZE))
            return;
    if((col < 0) || (col >= BOARDSIZE))
            return;

    if (visited[row][col])
            return;

    if (board[row][col] != ' ')
            return;

    visited[row][col] = true;

    count++;

    countSpaces((row - 1), col);
    countSpaces((row + 1), col);
    countSpaces(row, (col - 1));
    countSpaces(row, (col + 1));
    return;
}
```